# Recommended indentation style for Ruby `if` blocks that assign a value to a variable?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Which of these is better Ruby code formatting style, and why?

Option A:

```
def load_business
  @business ||= if params[:badge_uuid] 
    # some code
  else
    # some other code
  end
end
```

Option B:

```
def load_business
  @business ||= if params[:badge_uuid] 
                  # some code
                else
                  # some other code
                end
end
```

Comment: I would rather avoid both of them. Maybe create methods for both cases and use `?:` then?

Comment: I'd split out the entire if statement into a method.@business ||= business_value(params).

Comment: I don't understand why the question has been closed, it seems a valid question... style matters are very relevant in programming.

Comment: Where am I supposed to ask this kind of question then. Please suggest a forum, dear moderators.

Comment: A good "Option C" would be: stick a newline after the '=' char, but then with the 'if' block indented with two spaces after that, as in [this style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#use-if-case-returns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a subjective question, so we can only give (hopefully reasoned) opinions. I always use **option A**. My rationale:

1. The block of code is opened and closed at the same indentation-level, that creates a "visual cohesion".
2. If the variable name changes its size, you don't need to edit anything  (some text editors handle this automatically, though).
3. You create a "hole" in the source code. The larger the variable name, the bigger the hole. IMO this is visually annoying. Also, you have less space available till reaching some reasonable 80/100-char limit.

I use this style when writing multi-line hashes/arrays/... (note the comma also in the last element so we can re-order them easily and in diff-friendly way):

```
hash = {
  :a => 1,
  :b => 2,
}

array = [
  :a, 
  :b,
]
```

Comment: Point two is solved by getting a better text editor.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: Which editor would handle that case automatically?

Comment: @undur_gongor: Option B is EMACS' default way of indenting Ruby code (though it is configurable). Thus you can simply reindent the whole `if` statement with a simple press of TAB (or even let it do this automatically, if you are skilled in hacking elisp). I think in vim it's similarly easy.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Option A.

Here is some ActiveRecord code that is also that way.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb#L35

EDIT:

This is a pretty opinionated question, there likely is no right answer. Because of that no matter how you do it as long as it's not just ugly code people probably won't hold it against you.

Answer (score 2):

I would not be caught dead using the value of an `if` block. Maybe it's because I come from a background where `if` is a statement, not an expression... So my two cents are:

```
def load_business
  @business ||= (  params[:badge_uuid]
                 ? # some code
                 : # some other code)
end
```

If the pieces of code are not plain expressions, I would assign them to a value in each part of the `if` and assign use that variable to update `@business`.

Comment: As you say you suffer a taboo that stems from imperative-background. There are **lots** of languages (not necessarily functional) in which condition branches return expressions. Question: If you have an if block as the last expression of a method, do you leave it as an if, or you set the variable and then return that variable?

Comment: +1 for a spot-on question. Having been frustrated with the lack of `return` in Lisp for 20+ years, I would definitively assign the value to a variable and return it, alternatively place a `return` in each part of the `if`. When reading code without explicit return statements, it's not clear if a function intended to return something, or if that something just happened to be last in a function -- having compound constructs implicitly return the last value of each branch, makes code even harder to read. Personally, I think this is a major design flaw and in languages like Ruby.